# My django project not finding the new app

Tags: django

There's this problem am having right now where there's no error in my code and yet the code won't run. Am still a newbie trying out something

I developed a little django project and pushed to github, went to my pythonanywhere console and cloned it. Now I went back to console and created a new app ( **startapp** command) added to INSTALLED_APPS and added some lines of code in the new app.

Problem is that the URLs in the new are not going through and even the **ls** command is not listing the app

Is this a git issue?

Comment: Have you added urls from your app into the main urls?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. Post your comment as an answer so that I mark it

Comment: I think there is no need, cause there are lots of similar questions with answers. Feel free to do that if you want.